# Sliding tableViews (much like calendar)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What do you recommend would be the best way to create the sliding tableView effect seen in calendar, where you can "**swipe**" between tableViews?

Currently, the way I have it working is detecting swipe gestures, and then reloading 1 tableView based on the swipe direction. While this works, it doesn't look all that great. I really want the effect where as they drag right/left the next tableView is dragged in.

```
var rightRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipeFrom:")
rightRecognizer.direction = .Right
var leftRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipeFrom:")
leftRecognizer.direction = .Left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightRecognizer)
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftRecognizer)


func handleSwipeFrom(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    println(previousDays.count)

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:

            //call function to get new data
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            //call function to get new data
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        default:
            break
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: r u looking for something like this https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this , instead of using TableView, you can use `UICollectionView`.

Please refer following reference links to implement `UICollectionView`;

1) [Link 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)

2) [Link 2](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

3) [Link 3](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is create a UIScrollView that will scroll horizontally and add each TableView inside of that side by side.  You can then set the pagingEnabled property to yes so that when you scroll horizontally the scrollView will snap to show only one tableView at a time.

It is really quite fluid and simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use collection view and in each collection view cell contains tableview. you can also use scrollview but in scrollview you have to manage content-size and other thing and scrollview don't deallocate memory after scrolling while in collection view only load current cell memory.